# How do I define a two point random variable?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

How do I define a random variable $X$ such that $Pr[X=x_1]=p_1$ and $Pr[X=x_2]=p_2$ where the values $x_i$, $i=1,\,2$ are just symbols and the probabilities $p_i$, $i=1,\,2$ are symbolic expressions that add up to $1$?

Is the only way through `EmpiricalDistribution` resulting in (expression with head) a`DataDistribution` and not a `ProbabilityDistribution`?

Comment: Given that the (current) 3 answers are all "equivalent", I'm curious as to why you need an alternative to the EmpiricalDistribution approach.  Does it have to do with computational speed?  I ask because $X$ is just a linear combination of a standard binomial random variable (which takes on values of 0 and 1):  $X=x_1+Y(x_2-x_1)$.  It is likely (although I haven't tested it) that if you wanted to generate zillions of random values of $X$, maybe generating zillions of binomial variables and then transforming might be faster.  Stating more about your objective might get you better answers.

Comment: @JimBaldwin The real reason is that I need to work with mixtures of discrete and continuous random variables but `MixtureDistribution` does not work with such mixtures and so I need to write my own functions.  It seems that I need to work with, at least, two heads: `DataDistribution` and `ProbabilityDistribution`. I was curious if it is possible to "pack" everything into a `ProbabilityDistribution` expression. It seems like it is not possible.

Comment: Does `ParameterMixtureDistribution` not do what you want?

Comment: Specifically: `d = ParameterMixtureDistribution[
   MixtureDistribution[{x, 1 - x}, {NormalDistribution[mu1, sigma1], 
     NormalDistribution[mu2, sigma2]}], 
   x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1, p]];
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] d]`

Comment: @JimBaldwin I've just tested that, despite what is written in Mathematica help, `MixtureDistribution` actually works with a mix of continuous and discrete distributions! Here's an example: `MixtureDistribution[{1 - \[Delta], \[Delta]},
 {ProbabilityDistribution[Exp[-t], {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "Normalize"], 
  EmpiricalDistribution[{1 - s, s} -> {\[Delta], s^2}]}]`. `Mean`, `CDF`, `RandomVariate` (after substituting parameters with numbers) all work! The lesson I learnt: check everything! Thank you all for help, I learnt a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a `ProbabilityDistribution` for a two-point random variable, here is one way to do so:

```
x1 =.
x2 =.
p1 =.
twoPointRV = 
 TransformedDistribution[y x1 + (1 - y) x2, 
  y \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1, p1]]
```

Now you can use `twoPointRV` symbolically as a `ProbabilityDistribution`:

```
mean = Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] twoPointRV]
(* p1 x1+x2-p1 x2 *)

var = Expectation[x^2, x \[Distributed] twoPointRV] - mean^2
(* p1 x1^2+x2^2-p1 x2^2-(p1 x1+x2-p1 x2)^2 *)

PDF[twoPointRV, x1]
(* p1 *)

PDF[twoPointRV, x2]
(* 1-p1 *)
```

Comment: Great, this is precisely what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: After looking at the result it also returns an expression that is (has head) `TransformedDistribution` and not `ProbabilityDistribution`.

Comment: @Michal, why does the head matter to you in this case? Any of those are usable in `PDF[]`, `Probability[]`, `Expectation[]`, etc.

Comment: In fact, after looking at both solutions I prefer the best `EmpiricalDistribution`, then `DiracDelta` way and then `TransformerDistribution` (since it is not as flexible as the first two).

Comment: @J.M. `MixtureDistribution` does not work with continuous and discrete distributions at the same time so I need to write my own functions to deal with it. It seems that I need to work with, at least, two heads: `DataDistribution` and `ProbabilityDistribution`. I was  curious if it is possible to "pack" everything into a `ProbabilityDistribution` expression. It seems like it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify such a `ProbabilityDistribution` by using DiracDelta which have some interesting properties:

```
x1=1;
x2=0;
p1=.3;
p2=.7;

d = ProbabilityDistribution[p1 DiracDelta[x - x1] + p2 DiracDelta[
      x-x2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
RandomVariate[d]
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] d]
```

`ProbabilityDistribution` will automatically transfrom your distribution to another form, so you won't need to worry about specified range or so, Simply do `{x,-Infinity,Infinity}` will be OKAY!

Hope this can help you~

**Comment:**
This distribution is symbolic, you can do everything with it.
Easiest and most direct to define, I cannot find its drawback :P

Comment: This is nice, however, the results is `DataDistribution` and not `ProbabilityDistribution`.

Comment: @Michal Maybe I missed something, but what do you mean by saying DataDistribution? I surely used ProbabilityDistribution function.

Comment: I assume that `p1 = 0.3` and `p2 = 0.7`.  But what you give does not seem to incorporate `x1` and `x2` and `p1` and `p2` are not treated symbolically as requested.

Comment: @JimBaldwin so you want them to be symbolic?

Comment: @JimBaldwin edited, will this be okay?

Comment: @Wjx That looks like it would work.  (It's the OP the wanted things symbolic.)

Comment: oh yeah..... I assume you are the OP at the first time :P

Comment: Both solutions work (using `DiracDelta` and `TransformedDistribution`). The other way is to use `EmpiricalDistribution[{p, 1 - p} -> {x1, x2}]`. In fact this last one returns exactly the same thing as `ProbabilityDistribution[
 p  DiracDelta[x - x1] + (1 - p)  DiracDelta[x - x2], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}]`. The problem is that the result is an expressing with head `DataDistribution` and not `ProbabilityDistribution`. The same goes for the solution using `TransformedDistribution`, the results has head `TransformedDistribution`. Can I get a result with head `ProbabilityDistribution `?

Comment: @Michal so, now your concerm is Head of the result, right?

Comment: When asking a question I was aware of the `EmpiricalDistribution` way of defining such a r.v. Two other ways are OK and work but it seems strange to me that I cannot (as it seems) define such a r.v. as simply a `ProbabilityDistribution` (talking about the resulting expression as in the original question).

Comment: There is a difference in how Mathematica handles both approaches define `q1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{p1, p2} -> {x1, x2}]` and `q2 = ProbabilityDistribution[  p1  DiracDelta[x - x1] + p2  DiracDelta[x - x2], {x, -Infinity,    Infinity}]` and see `FullForm`. I was wrong in the other comment saying that these two are identical. They are sometimes but not in general.

Comment: @Michal in fact, they are identical...... Check fullform

Comment: The first one gives `DataDistribution["Empirical",List[List[Times[p1,Power[Plus[p1,p2],-1]],Times[p2,Power[Plus[p1,p2],-1]]],List[x1,x2],False],1,2]`. The second one gives `DataDistribution["Empirical",List[List[Times[p1,Power[Plus[Times[p1,Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]],Times[p2,Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]]],-1],Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]],Times[p2,Power[Plus[Times[p1,Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]],Times[p2,Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]]],-1],Power[Abs[Plus[p1,p2]],-1]]],List[x1,x2],False],1,2]`. Without any simplifications.

Comment: @Michal yes, but even fullsimplify can tell they are identical :)

Comment: @Wjx After simplifying they are identical, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at HistogramDistribution.  It provides a piecewise constant PDF.  Since it is a distribution object, you can use RandomVariate, Mean, etc. on it.